# Check if UIButton already exists on UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

For every `UITableViewCell` I'm creating a `UIButton` in the `tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath` method. I want to check if `UIButton` is already there when creating it, so it's not added multiple times, but I can't. Here's my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        UIImageView *cellBottomLine = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, CELL_HEIGHT, 320.0, 1)];
        cellBottomLine.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bottomCellImage.png"];
    if (cellBottomLine.subviews) {
        [cell addSubview:cellBottomLine];
    }

        copyButton = [BSFunctions createButtonWithNormalImageNamed:@"copyCellButton.png" highlightedImageName:@"copyCellButtonPressed.png" target:self selector:@selector(copyPressedFromCell:)];
        [copyButton setFrame:CGRectMake(250, 10, 62, 32.5)];
        copyButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    if (!copyButton.superview) {
        [cell addSubview:copyButton];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: why aren't you adding the button in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method?

Comment: I'll go with Kuba's suggestion you can add button while checking if cell is not nil by this way there'll be no redundancy as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     UIImageView *cellBottomLine = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, CELL_HEIGHT, 320.0, 1)];
cellBottomLine.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bottomCellImage.png"];
    if (cellBottomLine.subviews) 
    {
        [cell addSubview:cellBottomLine];
    }

    for (UIView *view in [cell subviews]) 
    {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) 
        {
             return cell;
        }
    }

    copyButton = [BSFunctions createButtonWithNormalImageNamed:@"copyCellButton.png"
                                          highlightedImageName:@"copyCellButtonPressed.png"
                                                        target:self
                                                      selector:@selector(copyPressedFromCell:)];
    [copyButton setFrame:CGRectMake(250, 10, 62, 32.5)];
    copyButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    if (!copyButton.superview)
    {
        [cell addSubview:copyButton];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Your answer does work, but oddly enough, every time when the cell is moved out of the size of UITableView it's added 1 subview at it's `cell.subviews`. Any ideas on what it might be?

Comment: it might be the "cellBottomLine" imageview you are adding, which will be added every time the function is called. I wrote the code specifically for the UIButton view as you asked. But if don't want to add imageView either(if it already exist) then let me know. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method for adding any subviews to cell, so that the cell will be reused when scrolling back and forth and you dont require any check before adding subviews to cell.

Comment: Unfortunately, when using the method proposed by you, when UITableView is scroll out of the view's contents the state of UIButtons resets.

Comment: Then there should be some bug in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method. Have you used reusable identifier in that method?

Comment: To address the resetting button issue, I think the usual technique is to build an array of cells in `viewDidLoad` (or a custom subroutine that `viewDidLoad` calls), then use `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to just display the cell at that index in the array.  As I understand it, putting the cells in an array will make them persist even if that cell isn't on screen, so UIControls don't get recreated (and therefore reset) when the cell is redisplayed.

Answer (score 1):

Stavash's answer is the best, but if you don't want to do that, alternatively you can use `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.  I saw that you tried that and that the state of the button was lost while scrolling.  I assume this is due to cell reuse.  With cell reuse, once a table view cell goes off the screen, it is cached with an identifier and then the next cell to come on the screen retrieves a cell with a given identifier from the cache.

To avoid the button losing its state when it goes off the screen, you can use multiple reuse identifiers and store the states of your buttons in an array.  We'll call this property `buttonStates` (it should be a mutable array).

Initialize your `buttonStates` variable and add strings to represent "base states."  Add as many of these strings as the number of cells in your table (I assume there is only one section based on your code).

When the state changes (this would probably happen in your `copyPressedFromCell:` method, update the object at the index of the button's tag (which you have already set to the index of the cell) with a string representing the new state.

With all that done, make your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method looks like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *CellIdentifier = self.buttonStates[indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Before we continue lets take a look at some of your `willDisplayCell:` code (which should be moved here).

```
UIImageView *cellBottomLine = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, CELL_HEIGHT, 320.0, 1)];
cellBottomLine.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bottomCellImage.png"];
if (cellBottomLine.subviews) {
    [cell addSubview:cellBottomLine];
}
```

Why are you running that if statement?  If you've just created a new image view, it's going to return `YES` every time (assuming that the array of subviews is not `nil` by default).  You would rather check if a bottom cell image already exists within the cell's subviews.  But we don't even need to do that.  Just add the image in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, inside the `!cell` if.  That way, we only add the `bottomCellImage` if the cell hasn't been created yet.

The same thing goes for your `if (!copyButton.superview)` call.  Continuing where we left of in our `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
        UIImageView *cellBottomLine = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, CELL_HEIGHT, 320.0, 1)];
        cellBottomLine.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bottomCellImage.png"];
        [cell addSubview:cellBottomLine];

        copyButton = [BSFunctions createButtonWithNormalImageNamed:@"copyCellButton.png"
                                      highlightedImageName:@"copyCellButtonPressed.png"
                                                    target:self
                                                  selector:@selector(copyPressedFromCell:)];
        [copyButton setFrame:CGRectMake(250, 10, 62, 32.5)];
        copyButton.tag = indexPath.row;
        [cell addSubview:copyButton];
    }

    UIButton *button = [cell viewWithTag:indexPath.row]; // Get the copy button
    // Update the state of the button here based on CellIdentifier, outside the if statement so that it gets updated no matter what
    // Also configure your cell with any non-button related stuffs here

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Why create `cellBottomLine` image twice? Where do we need `buttonStates` later in the code?

Comment: @SergiusGee I'm not creating it twice, I quoted your code to show you how to change it.  I explained where to use `buttonStates` elsewhere in you code.

Comment: My bad. Thanks for the overwhelming explanation, I'll try it out!

Comment: @SergiusGee no problem, let me know what your results are, I didn't have time to make a sample app and test it myself. :)

Comment: Even if I set the `copyButton.highlighted = YES` where you have the line `UIButton *button = [cell viewWithTag:indexPath.row]` if the table scrolls out - it still becomes UNhighlighted. It's starting to drive me crazy

Comment: @SergiusGee I don't think `highlighted` is the right property.  Try `selected` instead.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this altogether, why not subclass `UITableViewCell` and create a designated representation of that class in a storyboard/XIB? That way, when cells are reused, the OS will not create the UI elements again and again but rather reuse the ones that were already allocated from IBOutlets.

Comment: I don't use XIB or Storyboards

Comment: As a rule? A principle? What do you mean?

Comment: As a rule, yes. Have you ever merged XIBs? Or Storyboards? Laying out thing in code is a great way to do things, I think, and it's more reliable too.

Comment: To answer your question about merging - yes, I know about the headache involved with collaboration and XML-based files such as storyboards, xibs and project files. But I don't think it's a good enough excuse for ignoring them altogether. For example, no matter how you decide to tackle this specific issue - it will be far less elegant than implementing your cell in Interface Builder.

Comment: And here's something related I asked a long time ago, just to ensure you that I share your anger http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11538510/storyboards-and-svn-conflicts

Comment: Yes, maybe, but creating a Storyboard for a cell, no, that's no how I'd like to do that ;) Thanks anyway!

Comment: You can also create an UITableViewCell subclass in code. Why not choose that approach?

Comment: @WolfgangSchreurs that's what I'm trying to do here

Comment: If you're going to use an identical graphic representation for a UI element, as a rule of thumb I'd say build it with IB (would also require subclass in code). I'm not saying that pure code without IB is wrong, I just don't like when developers say "I don't do storyboards".

Comment: @SergiusGee well, if that's what you're trying to do, you're doing it wrong :) - You should create a new class, e.g. call it BSButtonCell and make it inherit from UITableViewCell. Configure frames of your button / image in either the initialiser or the `-layoutSubviews` method of the BSButtonCell. Remove the `-tableView:willDisplayCell:atIndexPath:` method from your view controller. Configure action method of button in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: @WolfgangSchreurs That's a great idea but it brings a lot of complexity in the app - I would have to manage the data between 2 classes and transmit input between them as well.

Comment: @SergiusGee Good design and complexity almost always collide during the first phase of creating an app. When there are bugs or performance issues, that's where the bad design comes back to haunt you.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can check it in this way:
1) put somewhere `copyButton = nil;` (in viewDidLoad, or somewhere else;
2) then:
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        UIImageView *cellBottomLine = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, CELL_HEIGHT, 320.0, 1)];
        cellBottomLine.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bottomCellImage.png"];
    if (cellBottomLine.subviews) {
        [cell addSubview:cellBottomLine];
    }
    if (!copyButton) {
        copyButton = [BSFunctions createButtonWithNormalImageNamed:@"copyCellButton.png" highlightedImageName:@"copyCellButtonPressed.png" target:self selector:@selector(copyPressedFromCell:)];
        [copyButton setFrame:CGRectMake(250, 10, 62, 32.5)];
        copyButton.tag = indexPath.row;
        if (!copyButton.superview) {
           [cell addSubview:copyButton];
        }
     }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, it creates a button only in the first cell

Answer (score 0):

Try in the following way

```
if ([cell viewWithTag:LBL_TAG])
{
    UIView *vi = (UIView*)[cell viewWithTag:LBL_TAG];
    if ([vi isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
    {
        UILabel *lbl = (UILabel*)vi;
        NSLog(@"test  %@..",lbl.text);
    }
}
```

Hope it may help you.