# Best way to handle xcode Storyboard in iOS while using SVN

Tags: ios, svn, storyboard

What is the best way to handle the storyboard with multiple developer while using SVN. I'm facing issue while commit with other developers storyboard.

Comment: Hopefully this answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11538510/storyboards-and-svn-conflicts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a team to work on the same app it's recommended that every developer creates a separate storyboard file for the feature / module he working on that way no conflicts would happen ,  only drawBack i think is that instead of easily using `self.storyboard` , you have to create the storyboard object corresponding to the name of the storyboard you created but it can be handled with a simple extension

Comment: i think is not a good way to continue the work , better you can use storyboard refrerence

Answer (score 0):

I would personally prefer taking multiple storyboards in such a situation. Use [**storyboard references**](https://cocoacasts.com/organizing-storyboards-with-storyboard-references) as much as you can. This will not only help your developers to independently work with their storyboards, but it would also separate multiple functionality or to be specific, modules, from each other.