# XCode 5 : svn discard is grayed out on storyboard file

Tags: xcode, svn, storyboard, xcode5

This picture explains it better than words. You can see that the storyboard file is modified, but SVN Discard option is grayed out.

[image]

This is a real PITA because, XCode treats storybard file in such a way that [it gets modified just from opening it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233181/xcode-changes-unmodified-storyboard-and-xib-files). My only workaround right now is to discard the changes in command line using `svn revert` command.

Is this a bug? Or is there any settings to change it?

Comment: I am experiencing the same. Probably it's a bug. Mark Selected files as Resolved is also not working, when the file had a conflict. Probably bugs...

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem as well, I found that I can use commit from the Source Control Menu option but can not discard an individual file from there, only all files. It is a PITA for sure.

Edit: I found another work-around. You can use File Inspector, scroll down to the source control section and you will see a Discard button. I just tried it and it works.

Comment: I knew the first workaround, the second one was new to me. Thanks. Definitely a PITA though.