# Xcode change storyboard's frame value automatically cause git merge conflict all the time. How to solve it?

Tags: xcode, git, uistoryboard

Every time when I merge other team member's iOS objc project, I got some strange conflict like this:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
    <rect key="frame" x="254.00000003476939" y="0.0" width="63" height="21"/>
=======
    <rect key="frame" x="254.00000010362709" y="0.0" width="63" height="21"/>
>>>>>>> XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

We never change the value of x, and we always give integer like value. Obviously, Xcode changed the value automatically.
How to prevent this kind things happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could avoid checking in such modified value by convincing Git that the file content has *not* changed.

That is possible with a **`clean`** script which will be in charge of keeping only an integer value for x.
That script will be applied only to the `.storyboard` files (as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24866109/6309)), and will have to replace "254.xxx" by "254".

```
 sed -i 's/x=\"([0-9]+).*\"/x=\"\1\"/g'
```

The restoration of the file through that script is automated through a **[content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571580/6309)**, using a [`.gitattributes` declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309).

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tumAc.png]
<sup>(image from ["Customizing Git - Git Attributes"](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion) from "[Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/)"))</sup>

Once you declare that content filer driver in your local git config, it will automatically, on `git commit`, restore the file.
Or it will consider the file as unchanged on `git diff`/`git status`, even when XCode modified that value.

See a complete example in "[Best practice - Git + Build automation - Keeping configs separate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20822928/6309)".

Comment: I was testing the regex here https://regex101.com/ but whatever i put `254.987` or `"254.987"` or `x="254.987"` it doesnt transform it to `254` but it transform it to the same input i give, any idea why?

Comment: @denis_lor can you share the regex101.com link to the specific regex and test you were using?

Comment: @denis_lor I have edited the answer and fixed the regex: https://regex101.com/r/9BR5BC/1

Comment: doesn't work if you put `x="254.987"testtest` it highlights everything, also `testtest`

Comment: @denis_lor That will work with the regex in the answer, which I have reported in https://regex101.com/r/9BR5BC/2.