# Is there a way to get git commit --verbose to show an updated diff when using pre-commit hooks?

Tags: python, git, commit, verbose, python-black

So I'm currently setting up a git pre-commit hook to lint my python files with iSort, and python Black, the issue I'm running into is that when I use `git commit --verbose` the diff that shows up in the commit editor hasn't actually taken the modifications to the staged files into account.

For example, lets say I have a python file that looks like so:

```py
import re

from os import path

def x():
    v = re.compile(r"1")
    print(3, v)

def y(v=3):
    z = path.join("a", "b")
    thing = "a string"
    print(thing, z)
```

Based on the iSort and black settings I have configured, my pre-commit script will change the file to look like so:

```
import re
from os import path


def x():
    v = re.compile(r"1")
    print(3, v)


def y(v=3):
    z = path.join("a", "b")
    thing = "a string"
    print(thing, z)
```

Unfortunately in the git commit editor it still shows the non modified diff. Is there some way to get the editor to have the correct output?

Theoretically I guess it doesn't matter, but it would be nice to see what the diff would actually be.

Comment: Does the pre-commit hook stage (`git add`) changed files?

Comment: Yes it does. After I do the commit and look at the file, the changes have been made and committed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a pre-commit hook, try instead a content filter driver, with a smudge/clean script which can:

- on checkout make your script one way
- on commit (or on git diff) make your script the other way

See an [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20822928/6309) or [(for clean) here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47491876/6309)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tumAc.png]
<sup>(image from ["Customizing Git - Git Attributes"](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion) from "[Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/)"))</sup>

Comment: Hmm good idea. I took a try at implementing a clean/smudge solution this morning but I'm still running into a bit of an issue. The diffs and commits looks great now, as it does what I want it to. The weird thing is that the local file doesn't seem to be modified at all, but I would expect it to look the same as what was committed. Am I doing something wrong? 

Here is a copy of my clean/smudge script I am using https://pastebin.com/mCPg7rbE

Comment: @DJSymBiotiX The goal is to *generate* a private local file, not to modify an existing file.

Comment: hmm well I guess then this isn't quite what I'm looking for, based on my initial question/problem.

Comment: @DJSymBiotiX You can modifiy an existing file, but you have to make sure your smudge/clean scripts are "symetrical": the changes added by one are removed by the other. Then `touch yourFile` and `git checkout -- .` to force the smudge script to re-apply.

Comment: Well that seems counter intuitive. You can't really "undo" a linting function.

Comment: Right, In your case a smudge would be enough. No need to reverse the modification