# Storyboards constraints suddenly all misplaced

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode-storyboard

I am using XCode 6.4. I have quite a big Storyboard, and sometimes, when I open it, lots of warnings appear out of the blue, saying I have misplaced views, without touching anything. Everything was fine before, and the misplaced views are in every single viewcontroller. I add most of the constraints manually.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong, or why suddenly everything moves?

**EDIT**

I pull from the repo, open XCode, and then all the warnings appear. If I `git status`, the storyboard has changed. 
The difference between the versions is on the `systemVersion` attribute on the Storyboard. That change probably happens automatically when someone else with another configuration opens the project and then commits the changes. 
This (long) question is related: [Xcode changes unmodified storyboard and XIB files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233181/xcode-changes-unmodified-storyboard-and-xib-files). However, my problem is not on the `class` attribute, but on the `systemVersion`

Comment: What happens when you open it in an older version of Xcode?

Comment: @Tander I don't have an older version on this mac right now, but I'll try later on another mac. The only issue is that the problem is hard to reproduce. I don't know what I am doing to cause this, and does not happen everytime.

Comment: I find large storyboards to be painful. My SB in my project is also big and get these sorts of errors. Not as serious - but random things. I normally just clean build and it fixes it.

Comment: @Tander, yes, I am finding the hard way that big storyboards are annoying.    Cleaning is not helping. However I have found that what has changed is the systemVersion. Probably a collaborator opened it in his xcode, change stuff, I do the pull, open it and then its all wrong. Probably will edit and add this.

Comment: Oh yeah, I found them even more fragile with source control and multiple developers.

Comment: @jrf As I understand it, automatic change of the tools version tag is there exactly for better compatibility between different IDE versions. You might want to check the file changes log instead to see what's been changed by the colleague who clearly at least opened it once. If there's no changes done by others but the version tag, this would be an important information to know at this context.

Comment: @A-Live What is being changed is the systemVersion tag. Was that your question?