# How to stop InterfaceBuilder from meddling with my storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, xcode-storyboard

I am using XCode 7.2.1.

In it, InterfaceBuilder has this nasty habit of doing some changes to my storyboard when I just view it.

As example, I just opened it and now I can see in the diff that it changed (I have no idea why) bounds of several controls. For example it changes this

```
<rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="560" height="43"/>
```

to

```
<rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="560" height="43.5"/>
```

I still can't figure out when it's doing it. Sometimes everything works fine for a day and sometimes it goes into this state that as soon as I open a storyboard IB starts meddling with it.

Two questions:

- Is there a way to turn this thing off?
- Do you know when is starts automatically updating it (may be I can workaround it).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode changes unmodified storyboard and XIB files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233181/xcode-changes-unmodified-storyboard-and-xib-files)