# Changed found in source tree from non-changed storyboard/xib

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, xib

I am using source tree to manage the version control, a strange thing happened on storyboard/xib.

Source tree detected changes in storyboard/xib files even if I only click the storyboard/xib, not even moving anything in it.

I discard the changes every time if I am not adding or moving stuff in it. But I wonder if I take the changes in the storyboard, is it OK or not? Or there is no difference?

I also wonder what is the reason this happens.

Thanks for any reply.

Edit: the changes are on the `toolsVersion = "..."` as well as the `dependency version`

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233181/xcode-changes-unmodified-storyboard-and-xib-files

Comment: well I saw that one, but I am facing this issue, I want to know is it better to solve the conflict by taking the new changes as in the source tree

Comment: If you touch the storyboard or xib even by slightly moving the views unintentionally, source tree will detect it. And it is intentional. You can't do anything with that, you need to live with it and resolve the issue by discarding the change, simple as that.